# Why my javascript alert() code is running before <h1> html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<h1>Paragraph 1</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert ("section one bottom");
</script>
```

I have added my script after the `<h1>` tag but still `<h1>` is running after my `alert()` in javascript. Why? Could you explain? I am a beginner in web development.

Comment: https://eager.io/blog/everything-I-know-about-the-script-tag/

Comment: Because the browser first read everything before render you page.

so the js will directly fire the alert

Comment: @auryn31 - Browsers can and sometimes do render before reading the entire page (but not with something as short as the OP's example, granted).

Comment: Alert has paused the execution of the page. Once closed it will resume, and page gets rendered

Answer (score 7):

The `h1` element will exist before the `alert` happens, but it may not be *rendered* yet (actually visually, um, visible). JavaScript on web browsers has a single main UI thread per window¹ (sometimes more than one window share a single thread). In most browsers, that UI thread is usually also used for rendering. `alert` and the other 1990s functions (`prompt`, `confirm`) are unusual in that they stop the main UI thread for the window completely and wait for the user to do something. Most browsers can't even render when the `alert` is showing.

In general, avoid `alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt` — for several reasons: The issue above, the fact that their UI is fairly clunky, and the fact that browsers are slowly changing how they work (particularly when a tab/window is inactive) meaning they *don't* always stop-the-UI-world anymore, in ways that vary from browser to browser.

---

¹ That **doesn't** mean JavaScript is single-threaded. JavaScript itself has relatively little to say about threads, leaving it largely to the host environment (though recent specs have started to change that). On browsers, you can have multiple threads via [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/); these days, they can even [share memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) (temporarily disabled in most browsers, but will be able to again soon).